# Efficiently match multiple strings/keywords to multiple texts in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, string-search

I am trying to efficiently map exact peptides (short sequences of amino acids in the 26 character alphabet A-Z<sup>1</sup>) to proteins (longer sequences of the same alphabet). The most efficient way to do this I'm aware of is an `Aho-Corasick` trie (where peptides are the keywords). Unfortunately I can't find a version of AC in R that will work with a non-nucleotide alphabet (Biostrings' `PDict` and Starr's `match_ac` are both hard-coded for DNA).

As a crutch I've been trying to parallelize a basic grep approach. But I'm having trouble figuring out a way to do so without incurring significant IO overhead. Here is a brief example:

```
peptides = c("FSSSGGGGGGGR","GAHLQGGAK","GGSGGSYGGGGSGGGYGGGSGSR","IISNASCTTNCLAPLAK")
if (!exists("proteins"))
{
  biocLite("biomaRt", ask=F, suppressUpdates=T, suppressAutoUpdate=T)
  library(biomaRt)
  ensembl = useMart("ensembl",dataset="hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
  proteins = getBM(attributes=c('peptide', 'refseq_peptide'), filters='refseq_peptide', values=c("NP_000217", "NP_001276675"), mart=ensembl)
  row.names(proteins) = proteins$refseq_peptide
}

library(snowfall)
library(Biostrings)
library(plyr)
sfInit(parallel=T, cpus=detectCores()-1)

allPeptideInstances = NULL
i=1
increment=100
count=nrow(proteins)
while(T)
{
  print(paste(i, min(count, i+increment), sep=":"))
  text_source = proteins[i:min(count, i+increment),]
  text = text_source$peptide

  #peptideInstances = sapply(peptides, regexpr, text, fixed=T, useBytes=T)
  peptideInstances = sfSapply(peptides, regexpr, text, fixed=T, useBytes=T)
  dimnames(peptideInstances) = list(text_source$refseq_peptide, colnames(peptideInstances))

  sparsePeptideInstances = alply(peptideInstances, 2, .fun = function(x) {x[x > 0]}, .dims = T)

  allPeptideInstances = c(allPeptideInstances, sparsePeptideInstances, recursive=T)
  if (i==count | nrow(text_source) < increment)
    break
  i = i+increment
}

sfStop()
```

There are a few issues here:

- `peptideInstances` here is a dense matrix, so
  returning it from each worker is very verbose. I have broken it up
  into blocks so that I'm not dealing with a 40,000 (proteins) x 60,000
  (peptides) matrix.
- Parallelizing over peptides, when it would make
  more sense to parallelize over the proteins because they're bigger.
  But I got frustrated with trying to do it by protein because:
- This code breaks if there is only one protein in text_source.

Alternatively, if anyone is aware of a better solution in R, I'm happy to use that. I've spent enough time on this I probably would have been better served implementing Aho-Corasick.

<sup>1</sup> Some of those are ambiguity codes, but for simplicity, ignore that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned Rcpp and implemented an Aho-Corasick myself. Now CRAN has a good general purpose multiple-keyword search [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AhoCorasickTrie/index.html).

Here are some usage examples:

```
listEquals = function(a, b) { is.null(unlist(a)) && is.null(unlist(b)) || !is.null(a) && !is.null(b) && all(unlist(a) == unlist(b)) }

# simple search of multiple keywords in a single text
keywords = c("Abra", "cadabra", "is", "the", "Magic", "Word")
oneSearch = AhoCorasickSearch(keywords, "Is Abracadabra the Magic Word?")
stopifnot(listEquals(oneSearch[[1]][[1]], list(keyword="Abra", offset=4)))
stopifnot(listEquals(oneSearch[[1]][[2]], list(keyword="cadabra", offset=8)))
stopifnot(listEquals(oneSearch[[1]][[3]], list(keyword="the", offset=16)))
stopifnot(listEquals(oneSearch[[1]][[4]], list(keyword="Magic", offset=20)))
stopifnot(listEquals(oneSearch[[1]][[5]], list(keyword="Word", offset=26)))

# search a list of lists
# * sublists are accessed by index
# * texts are accessed by index
# * non-matched texts are kept (to preserve index order)
listSearch = AhoCorasickSearchList(keywords, list(c("What in", "the world"), c("is"), "secret about", "the Magic Word?"))
stopifnot(listEquals(listSearch[[1]][[1]], list()))
stopifnot(listEquals(listSearch[[1]][[2]][[1]], list(keyword="the", offset=1)))
stopifnot(listEquals(listSearch[[2]][[1]][[1]], list(keyword="is", offset=1)))
stopifnot(listEquals(listSearch[[3]], list()))
stopifnot(listEquals(listSearch[[4]][[1]][[1]], list(keyword="the", offset=1)))
stopifnot(listEquals(listSearch[[4]][[1]][[2]], list(keyword="Magic", offset=5)))
stopifnot(listEquals(listSearch[[4]][[1]][[3]], list(keyword="Word", offset=11)))

# named search of a list of lists
# * sublists are accessed by name
# * matched texts are accessed by name
# * non-matched texts are dropped
namedSearch = AhoCorasickSearchList(keywords, list(subject=c(phrase1="What in", phrase2="the world"),
                                                   verb=c(phrase1="is"),
                                                   predicate1=c(phrase1="secret about"),
                                                   predicate2=c(phrase1="the Magic Word?")))
stopifnot(listEquals(namedSearch$subject$phrase2[[1]], list(keyword="the", offset=1)))
stopifnot(listEquals(namedSearch$verb$phrase1[[1]], list(keyword="is", offset=1)))
stopifnot(listEquals(namedSearch$predicate1, list()))
stopifnot(listEquals(namedSearch$predicate2$phrase1[[1]], list(keyword="the", offset=1)))
stopifnot(listEquals(namedSearch$predicate2$phrase1[[2]], list(keyword="Magic", offset=5)))
stopifnot(listEquals(namedSearch$predicate2$phrase1[[3]], list(keyword="Word", offset=11)))

# named search of multiple texts in a single list with keyword grouping and aminoacid alphabet
# * all matches to a keyword are accessed by name
# * non-matched keywords are dropped
proteins = c(protein1="PEPTIDEPEPTIDEDADADARARARARAKEKEKEKEPEPTIDE",
             protein2="DERPADERPAPEWPEWPEEPEERAWRAWWARRAGTAGPEPTIDEKESEQUENCE")
peptides = c("PEPTIDE", "DERPA", "SEQUENCE", "KEKE", "PEPPIE")
peptideSearch = AhoCorasickSearch(peptides, proteins, alphabet="aminoacid", groupByKeyword=T)
stopifnot(listEquals(peptideSearch$PEPTIDE, list(list(keyword="protein1", offset=1),
                                                 list(keyword="protein1", offset=8),
                                                 list(keyword="protein1", offset=37),
                                                 list(keyword="protein2", offset=38))))
stopifnot(listEquals(peptideSearch$DERPA, list(list(keyword="protein2", offset=1),
                                               list(keyword="protein2", offset=6))))
stopifnot(listEquals(peptideSearch$SEQUENCE, list(list(keyword="protein2", offset=47))))
stopifnot(listEquals(peptideSearch$KEKE, list(list(keyword="protein1", offset=29),
                                              list(keyword="protein1", offset=31),
                                              list(keyword="protein1", offset=33))))
stopifnot(listEquals(peptideSearch$PEPPIE, NULL))

# grouping by keyword without text names: offsets are given without reference to the text
names(proteins) = NULL
peptideSearch = AhoCorasickSearch(peptides, proteins, groupByKeyword=T)
stopifnot(listEquals(peptideSearch$PEPTIDE, list(1, 8, 37, 38)))
stopifnot(listEquals(peptideSearch$DERPA, list(1, 6)))
stopifnot(listEquals(peptideSearch$SEQUENCE, list(47)))
stopifnot(listEquals(peptideSearch$KEKE, list(29, 31, 33)))
```

Comment: Nice!  Perhaps you could add an example (or two) using your package